# Error in my Google App Script code for Google Forms to Google Sheet to Google Contacts

Tags: google-apps-script, drive

I am pretty new to GAS & coding. Any help welcome.
I am getting data in to Google Sheets from a Google Form and have a script to trigger on form submit to put it into Google Contacts (new or update current), but I get an error and I can't work it out.

```
I get a code 3 error around e.namedValues; in line 3. - Any help is welcome.
```

Here is the code:

```
function formSubmitted(e){

 const info = e.namedValues;

 const contactArray = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(info['Email Address']);

 if(contactArray.length === 0){
   addContact(info);
 } else {
   updateContact(contactArray[0],info);
 }

}


function addContact(info) {

  const c = ContactsApp.createContact(info['First Name'], info['Last Name'],info['Email Address']);
  c.addCompany(info['Company'],"");
  c.addPhone(ContactsApp.Field.MAIN_PHONE, info['Phone']);
  const cg = ContactsApp.getContactGroup();
  c.addToGroup(cg[3]);
}


function updateContact(c,info) {

  c.setGivenName(info['First Name']);
  c.setFamilyName(info['Last Name']);
  c.setFullName(info['First Name'] + " " + info['Last Name']);
  c.getCompanies()[0].setCompanyName(info['Comapny']);
  c.getPhones()[0].setPhoneNumber(info['Phone']);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message you are getting? How are you trying to execute this? Are you sure you installed [the right kind of trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit())?

Comment: 11:12:08 PM Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
formSubmitted @ Code.gs:3

Comment: Trigger Choose which function to run = form ....  Submitted
Select event type = On form Submit

Comment: Are you trying to run `formSubmitted` from your script editor? This function should be run via trigger, not manually executing it through the editor. If you do that, `e` is undefined. That's most probably the cause of the error you are seeing.

Comment: Hiya once again, the script is saved and I run it from by entering data on the form. I have found the error info under the "Executions" and it now is reporting - Exception: The parameters () don't match the method signature for ContactsApp.getContactGroup.
    at addContact(Code:33:26)
    at formSubmitted(Code:21:5)

Comment: [getContactGroup](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/contacts-app#getcontactgroupname) requires you to provide the name of the group, and you are not providing any parameter. Also, this is a different error than the one you mentioned in your question, so I think your original question has already been solved and your new issue doesn't belong here (probably you were running from the editor, as I mentioned in my last comment; is that correct? In that case I'd consider explaining this issue in an answer for documentation purposes).

Answer (score 0):

```
function formSubmitted(e){
  const info = e.namedValues;
  const contact = ContactsApp.getContactsByEmailAddress(info['Email Address'][0]);
  if (contact) {
    addContact(info);
  } else {
    updateContact(contact, info);
  }

}
```